# Magnificer Popup uses multiple Slots for the same Picture

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, image-gallery, magnific-popup

the Magnificer Popup works, but when i open a picture and want to scroll to the left or right i need to click multiple times because it initialize
 1 picture as multiple. Also the picture count in the bottom is more than the actual pictures i have.

JS:

```js
  $('.image-link').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        removalDelay: 300,
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true
        }
    });
```

I hope you understand me and can help me.

Comment: please provide snippet that shows your problem

Comment: https://ibb.co/K6vkt5R and i have only around 40pictures. If i wannt to scroll throght the gallery the counter increases but only after around 3times the next picture shows

Comment: without code, StackOverflow not helps you

Comment: I've added the js code as you can see in the question

Comment: without HTML, we can render your error